# How to overwrite onPreviewFrame data with static YUV frame?

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera, webrtc, yuv

My application overrides the onPreviewFrame callback to pass the current camera frame to a webrtc native function. This works perfectly, however I want to be able to switch to sending a static frame instead of video, if that option has been selected in my app.

So far I have created a YUV NV21 image, which I am storing in the assets dir. All attempts to pass that frame down to the native function have resulted in purple/green stripes rather than the actual image.

This is what I have so far;

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    previewBufferLock.lock();

    if (mFrameProvider.isEnabled()) {
         mFrameProvider.overwriteWithFrame(data, expectedFrameSize);
    }

    if (isCaptureRunning) {
        if (data.length == expectedFrameSize) {
             ProvideCameraFrame(data, expectedFrameSize, context);
             cameraUtils.addCallbackBuffer(camera, data);
        }
    }
    previewBufferLock.unlock();
}


@Override
public byte[] overwriteWithPreviewFrame(byte[] data, int expectedFrameSize) {
   if (mFrameData == null) {
       loadPreviewFrame();
   }

   for (int i=0; i < expectedFrameSize; i++) {
        if (i < mFrameData.length) {
        data[i] = mFrameData[i];
        }
   }

   return data;
}
```

And

```
private void loadPreviewFrame() {
    try {
        InputStream open = mContext.getResources().getAssets().open(PREVIEW_FRAME_FILE);

        mFrameData = IOUtils.toByteArray(open);
        open.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", "", e);
    }
}
```

I have tried converting the image to a bitmap too. So the question is how can I open a YUV frame from assets and convert it into a suitable format to pass to the native methods.

Results in the following output;

[image]

Comment: If you're seeing *an* image, then you're apparently having some success replacing the camera output.  Are you sure that your image is correctly formed?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried it with YUV sample frames that are available online.. :(

Comment: Does the purple/green stripe output look the same regardless of the image you provide?  (Or different on subsequent runs with the same image?)  Just trying to figure out if you're seeing a distorted version of your image, or garbled data from somewhere else.

Comment: The image I get seems to be green/purple, on certain image the you can make out parts of the actual image, I have attached an example.

Comment: I'm puzzled about the ~30% loss of data, could it be that your sample frames were formatted YUV 4:2:2?

Comment: Converting a JPG to a NV21 image using ffmeg resulted in a NV21 image being around 30% larger, not 100% sure why. Which is why not I am doing the processing within Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right after a long fight with Android API I have managed to get this working.

There were two issues that caused the green/purple output;

**Loss of data:** the generated YUV frame was larger than the original preview frame at the same resolution, so the data being passed down to the native code was missing around 30% of its image data.

**Wrong resolution:** the native code required the resolution of the preview frame and not the camera.

Below is a working solution for anyone who wishes to add a static frame;

so updated code:

```
@Override
public byte[] getPreviewFrameData(int width, int height) {
    if (mPreviewFrameData == null) {
        loadPreviewFrame(width, height);
    }

    return mPreviewFrameData;
}

private void loadPreviewFrame(int width, int height) {
    try {
        Bitmap previewImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.frame);
        Bitmap resizedPreviewImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(previewImage, width, height, false);

        BitmapConverter bitmapConverter = new BitmapConverter();
        mPreviewFrameData = bitmapConverter.convertToNV21(resizedPreviewImage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("DisabledCameraFrameProvider", "Failed to loadPreviewFrame");
    }
}

class BitmapConverter {
    byte [] convertToNV21(Bitmap bitmap) {
        int inputWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        int inputHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

        int [] argb = new int[inputWidth * inputHeight];

        bitmap.getPixels(argb, 0, inputWidth, 0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight);

        byte [] yuv = new byte[inputWidth*inputHeight*3/2];
        encodeYUV420SP(yuv, argb, inputWidth, inputHeight);

        bitmap.recycle();

        return yuv;
    }

    void encodeYUV420SP(byte[] yuv420sp, int[] argb, int width, int height) {
        final int frameSize = width * height;

        int yIndex = 0;
        int uvIndex = frameSize;

        int R, G, B, Y, U, V;
        int index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                R = (argb[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                G = (argb[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
                B = (argb[index] & 0xff);

                Y = ( (  66 * R + 129 * G +  25 * B + 128) >> 8) +  16;
                U = ( ( -38 * R -  74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
                V = ( ( 112 * R -  94 * G -  18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;

                yuv420sp[yIndex++] = (byte) ((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
                if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0) {
                    yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte)((V<0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));
                    yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte)((U<0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
                }

                index ++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then finally in your callback;

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

     byte[] bytes = data;

     if (!mProvider.isVideoEnabled()) {
         Camera.Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
         bytes = mProvider.getPreviewFrameData(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
     }

     ProvideCameraFrame(bytes, bytes.length, context);
}
```

The key was to scale the image to the camera preview size and convert the image to YUV colour space.